# withUrqlClient does'nt work when activate ssr?

Tags: graphql, next.js, urql

Here's my code , and I think I follow the next-urql instruction completely,

```js
import { withUrqlClient } from "next-urql"
import { dedupExchange,cacheExchange,fetchExchange,ssrExchange } from "urql";
// import { cacheExchange } from "@urql/exchange-graphcache";
import { Navbar } from "../components/Navbar"
import { useTodosQuery } from "../generated/graphql";
import { createUrqlClient } from "../utils/createUrqlClient"

const Index = () => {
  const [{data}] = useTodosQuery();
  return(
    <>
    <Navbar/>
    <div>Hello world</div>
    <br></br>
    {!data ? (<div>Loading...</div>): data.todos.map((todo) => <div key={todo.id}>{todo.title}</div>)}
    </>
  )
};

export default withUrqlClient( (ssrExchange:any)=>({
  url:'https://localhost:4000/graphql',
  //for the cookie to workz
  fetchOptions:{
    credentials:"include" 
  },
  //for cache update
  exchanges: [dedupExchange,cacheExchange, ssrExchange, fetchExchange]
}))(Index);
```

So here's the thing , it works fine when I don't set {ssr:true}, but in order to use server-side-rendering I have to activate it , and after that , My website would'nt send any request to my server, so it failed to work , I wonder why is that

Answer (score 0):

I think here is the error:

```
  url:'https://localhost:4000/graphql',
```

instead of "https" use "http"

Comment: I use the right URL, still not working.